# Using GetUTCDate in SQL Server CE 4

Tags: sql-server-ce, webmatrix, sql-server-ce-4

Consider a SQL Server CE 4 table with a non-nullable column: `FooDate`. The goal is to have the current UTC datetime as the default.

> The function is not recognized by SQL Server Compact. Name of function GetUTCDate.

The function `GetDate()` works as expected as a default to a `datetime` column in SQL Server Compact 4.

Is `GetUTCDate()` supported in SQL Server CE 4 at all?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server CE supports a limited subset of T-SQL functions. GetUTCDate() is not one of them.

Comment: LAME, especially now that ms tries to say that this is a tool for websites.

Comment: SUPERLAME, especially they force you to use utc with azure